# async constructor in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to run 'Mongoose' and only continue my task when it's connected, but what happens is that the task runs first and then connects the Mongo

```js
export class App {
    constructor() {
        console.log("a1");
        this.config();
        console.log("a2");
    }
    public async config() {
        // Connect to MongoDB
        console.log("b1");
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(stringConnection, { useNewUrlParser: true }).finally();

            console.log("MongoDB Running");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            process.exit();
        }
        console.log("b2");
    }
}
```

Answer:

```
a1
b1
a2


MongoDB Running
b2
```

Answer I wanted:

```
a1
b1


MongoDB Running
b2
a2
```

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous constructor is potentially an antipattern, exactly because it doesn't provide proper control flow when an instance is created. It's expected that an instance is ready to use when it's created with `new` but it isn't ready.

A proper way to handle this is to have asynchronous hooks that are executed outside the class:

```
export class App {
    constructor() {}

    async init() {
        console.log("a1");
        await this.config();
        console.log("a2");
    }

    async config() {
       ...
    }
}

...

const app = new App();
await app.init();
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, but when I instantiate "new Class ()" it gets async again, so it ends up running the code from below and then starting the mongo

Comment: @wellington.silverio Yes, it's asynchronous, because promises and `async` are in use. I'm not sure why this is a problem. `const app = new App(); await app.init()` should result in a sequence you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Promise.then` (because `async` functions implicity return `Promise`s), stuff the things you want done after your `config()` in its `then` callback.

```
constructor() {
  console.log("a1");
  this.config().then(_ =>
    console.log("a2");
  });
}
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, but when I instantiate "new Class ()" it gets async again, so it ends up running the code from below and then starting the mongo

Comment: Code:
                console.log("1");
  const app = New App();
  console.log("2");
Response:
1
a1
b1
a2
2

MongoDB Running
b2

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to learn about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The good way to go could be to return in the config a Promise and after that you can use the then function in the Promise.

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, but when I instantiate "new Class ()" it gets async again, so it ends up running the code from below and then starting the mongo

Comment: Code:
                console.log("1");
  const app = new App();
  console.log("2");
Response:
1
a1
b1
a2
2

MongoDB Running
b2